Difficulty in Integrating LinkedIn API with Spring security for Oauth2
I am trying to configure spring security to login with oauth2 for Facebook, Google and Linkedin. Facebook seems to be working fine so is google. But LinkedIn is giving me a hard time. I am getting this error:
[missing_signature_verifier] Failed to find a Signature Verifier for Client Registration: 'linkedin'. Check to ensure you have configured the JwkSet URI. I need some help to fix this issue for successful Linkedin authentication. I have the permission in Linkedin app for profile, openid and email.
I went through other stackoverflow answers but none of the solutions helped. After going through as much stack overflow questions as I could, this is the code of my application currently:
application.yml
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          linkedin:
            clientId: ?
            clientSecret: ?
            scope: profile, email, openid
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "https://0a47-2405-201-a805-7211-4d70-a5b5-611c-fa27.ngrok-free.app/login/oauth2/code/linkedin"
            client-name: LinkedIn
            clientAuthenticationMethod: client_secret_post
        provider:
          linkedin:
            tokenUri: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
            authorizationUri: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization
            userInfoUri: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo
            userNameAttribute: id

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: TRACE

WebSecurityConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;


    @Bean
    public  SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/resources/**", "/logout")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauthLoginConfig -> oauthLoginConfig
                        .authorizationEndpoint((authorizationEndpointConfig ->
                                authorizationEndpointConfig.authorizationRequestResolver(
                                        requestResolver(this.clientRegistrationRepository)
                                ))
                        )
                        .tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpointConfig -> tokenEndpointConfig
                                .accessTokenResponseClient(linkedinTokenResponseClient())
                        )
                );
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }


    private static OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> linkedinTokenResponseClient() {
        var defaultMapConverter = new DefaultMapOAuth2AccessTokenResponseConverter();
        Converter<Map<String, Object>, OAuth2AccessTokenResponse> linkedinMapConverter = tokenResponse -> {
            var withTokenType = new HashMap<>(tokenResponse);
            withTokenType.put(OAuth2ParameterNames.TOKEN_TYPE, OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER.getValue());
            return defaultMapConverter.convert(withTokenType);
        };

        var httpConverter = new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter();
        httpConverter.setAccessTokenResponseConverter(linkedinMapConverter);

        var restOperations = new RestTemplate(List.of(new FormHttpMessageConverter(), httpConverter));
        restOperations.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());
        var client = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
        client.setRestOperations(restOperations);
        return client;
    }

    private static DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver requestResolver
            (ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver requestResolver =
                new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository,
                        "/oauth2/authorization");
        requestResolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(c ->
                c.attributes(stringObjectMap -> stringObjectMap.remove(OidcParameterNames.NONCE))
                        .parameters(params -> params.remove(OidcParameterNames.NONCE))
        );

        return requestResolver;
    }
}

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

you should use oauth2Client and not oauth2Login read the client chapter in the docs

@Toerktumlare Could you please elaborate on how I can write the above code using oauth2Client. I am using Spring security version 6.2.2 and it seems oauth2client from  org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity is deprecated. Does linkedin require additional configuration since it is not defined in CommonOAuth2Provider unlike Google, facebook or Github?

Why not read the chapter Oauth2Client in the official docs?
